# Help in naming my models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a library app I am writing. The models I have are `users` and `books`. Users can checkout books. What should I call the table that keeps track of the books that are loaned out to the users? Right now my top choice is `checkouts` but I'm not sure this is the best name.

So my models will look like:

```
User
    has_many :checkouts
    has_many :books, through :checkouts

Checkout
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :book

Book
    has_many :checkouts
    has_many :users, through :checkouts
```

Is there a better name I can use other than `checkout`?

Comment: This isn't a programming question, and doesn't belong here... But how about "loans"?

Comment: @BlackBear, maybe I'm just posting the question at the wrong place? At the very least this is a question about the design of my program.

Comment: @Songo: yep. Questions here are related to something which not works. I really don't know where you could ask this kind of question. What do you think about "abc" anyway? =P

Comment: I'd say this belongs on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Let's not turn this place into wikipedia.  Help with model naming is a programming concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BookLoans?  Loans?

I'd avoid checkout because it is ambiguous and also used a lot for shopping cart applications.

Comment: `loan` was another option I was looking at but I figured since this is JUST a library app, `checkout` seemed like a better name. I'm starting to like `BookLoan` though. It's funny how difficult finding a good name can be.